# How can a NSMutableArray object be cleared from all elements

Tags: ios, xcode

This is very basic but I don't know how to do it.
How can a NSMutableArray object be cleared from all elements.  I want to set the array to the state when it was created:

```
NSMutableArray  *myArray = [[NSMutableArray   alloc] init];
```

Thanks

Comment: very, very, very very basic indeed

Comment: Always look at Apple's Documentation first.  Its very simple and usually pretty thorough.  You can find fast answers to most simple questions there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[myArray removeAllObjects];`

Docs can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)